# how to apply color to heading before converting from json to excel or pdf or docs file

Tags: asp.net, json, typescript, angular8

This is the json data.I want to convert in excel or pdf files.

```
{  
   "Name":"B",
   "Age":22,
   "Gender":"Male",
   "Skills":{  
      ".Net":true,
      "Mule":""
   }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question.